# What is the maximum character level in Battleheart Legacy?

Tags: ios, battleheart-legacy

Simple question: what (if any) is the maximum level of player's character in Battleheart Legacy? I've tried Googling it but not found the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no maximum level in Battleheart: Legacy. Mike Mobile has explicitly stated so via Twitter:

[@Romance133](https://twitter.com/Romance133) No level cap, but the expectation is that in a "normal" play through you'll probably only master a couple classes

— Mika Mobile (@MikaMobile) [March 10, 2014](https://twitter.com/MikaMobile/status/443083446349352961)